# form_for Nested Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, rest

Here is the route:

```
 map.resources :networks do |network|
    network.resources :channels, :name_prefix => nil
  end
```

Here is what I have in my for my form.

```
<% form_for ([@network, @channel]) do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

I get an undefined method error since `form_for` is trying to call "network_channel_path". This error occurs because I have the channels `:name_prefix` as `nil`. How can I avoid this problem without completely writing out `form_form` with all the needed parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using `:name_prefix => nil` use `:shallow => true`

This will not display the `networks/:network_id` and not mess with your _paths

Comment: Using this method will require me to rework some of my views, mainly all of my path calls, but I do like this solution. Thanks!